# php include() error when included from another file

Tags: php

there is my php file structure:

practice-php

- index.php
- model

  - model.php
- connector

  - connectionUtility.php

---

in model php I write:
    include '../connector/connectionUtility.php';
in index.php
    include 'model/model.php';

---

when I run the 'model.php', there isn't any error, but when I run the 'index.php' the browser show:

require(../connector/connectionUltility.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\php-practice\model\model.php

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '../connector/connectionUltility.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp64\www\php-practice\model\model.php

---

I found out the answer for my question. If I write:
include 'connector/connectionUtility.php' in 'model.php', then I only need to inlcude 'model.php' in 'index.php'. The System will still understand.

---

Thank you all for helping.

Comment: Using the full path rather than a relative path usually solves this sort of thing. ie: `include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/connector/connectionUltility.php' );` or use `set_include_path` prior to using `include`

Comment: @ Ilaya Raja S When you put `..` it goes one folder back so in `index.php` it tries to include it from `www` direction

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `../connector/connectionUltility.php` in `model.php` and `connector/connectionUltility.php` in index.php

practice-php

- index.php
- model

  - model.php
- connector

  - connectionUtility.php

`../connector/connectionUltility.php` dots `..` mean that it goes one folder backwards so in `model.php` it goes back to `practice-php` direction than it goes to `connection/connectionUtility.php`

But when you use it in `index.php` that is already in `practise-php` direction and because of dots `..` it goes back to `www` direction than it tries to go `connector/connectionUltility.php`

Sorry for bad english

Comment: ' "@ Ilaya Raja S When you put .. it goes one folder back so in index.php it tries to include it from www direction" ' makes sense, thanks

Comment: Thank you, It work, but it can be a problem if I include another file in connectionUtility.php. Is there anyway that can solve the problem for every file in the project tree?

Comment: use absolute filenames `__DIR__` could be of help.

Comment: @Gii I'm not sure.